# Could you explain me the output of keras at each iteration?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When I train a sequential model with keras using the method **fit_generator**, I see this output

> Epoch 1/N_epochs
>
> n/N [====================>..............] - ETA xxxx - loss: yyyy

I noticed that the loss decreased gradually with the number of steps, as expected. My problem is that I also noticed that when one epoch finishes and another one starts, the value of the loss is quite different from the one that I see at the end of the previous epoch.

Why so? I thought that epoch and number of steps per epochs was arbitrary values and using, for instance, 10 epochs with 1000 steps should be the same of 1000 epochs with 10 steps. But what does exactly happen between one epoch and the next one in Keras 2.0?

*Disclaimer: I know the definition of epoch and how the number of steps should be decided using a batch generator, but I have too many data and I cannot apply this rule.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loss that Keras calculates during the epoch is accumulated and estimated online. So it includes the loss from the model after different weight updates.

Let we clarify with an easy case: assume for a second that the model is only improving (every weight update results in better accuracy and loss), and that each epoch contains 2 weight updates (each min-batch is half the training dataset).

At epoch X, the first mini-batch is processed and the result is a loss score 2.0.
After updating the weights, the model runs its second mini-batch which results in a loss score of 1.0 (for just the mini-batch). however you will see a loss of 2.0 change to 1.5 (average over all the dataset).

Now we start epoch X+1, but it happens after another weight update which leads to a loss of 0.8 over the first mini-batch, which is shown to you. And so on and on...

The same thing happens during your training, only that obviously, not all changes are positive.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the loss between the first and the second epoch is different for one reason :

The initializer when starting an epoch is random. So there is no continuity between the first and the second epoch.

This allows you to avoid getting stuck into local minimum and then use different values for your weights to get the minimum loss.

You can tune this parameters for each layer so.

You have, zeros, ones, constants, random normal, random uniform, lecun, glorot, Xavier & He..

Take a look at the doc here :

https://keras.io/initializers/ :)

Comment: Does this mean that at each epoch the training start again from scratch? If the weights are initialized at every epoch, which are the final weights of the model? And it also means that I should use a lot of steps per epoch and that epochs are not an arbitrary cutoff at all, differently as is explained in the keras documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the output of the keras function is a running average loss and the loss is quite a lot larger at the beginning of the epoch, than in the end. The loss is reset after each epoch and a new running average is formed. Therefore, the old running average is quite a bit higher (or at least different), than the beginning loss in the next epoch.